# HTML Rendering Time Recored in DynaTrace

Tags: html, css, performance, css-selectors

Do you know what factors will affect the "**Rendering**" time reported in **DynaTrace**?

I try to add inefficinet CSS selctors like "body table tr td.myStyle" to a big table element, yet there is no significant increasement on "Rendering Time". How can I conduct a experiment to see the changes on "Rendering" time?

Thanks.

Comment: Selector parsing is done separately from page rendering. No surprise there...

Comment: Are you trying to make your pages slower?

Answer (score 0):

Rendering activites includes the following
 a) actual drawing to the screen
 b) calculating layout
 c) parsing CSS resources
 d) scheduling layout tasks
We get these events by hooking into IE's rendering engine. You can view these different types of rendering activities by opening up your Hot Spots View and then filter for "Rendering"

If you spend a long time on your page and you have a lot of mouse overs that enable/disable certain DOM Elements it is very likely that you end up with a lot of rendering time. So - you always need to analyzed that time in correlation with the overall time you spent on that page

If you have more questions on dynatrace browser diagnostics I suggest you check out our discussion forums on http://community.dynatrace.com